# CKEDITOR - Wrap words into tag <span> when press ENTER_KEY

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to put new sentence in a `<span>` when `ENTER` key is pressed and when I start a new sentence ?

Actually when I press this key, I have `<p>Blablabla</p>` .

How to have this : `<p><span>Blablabla</span></p>` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, there's a way - on enter key wrap the text in a span. Did you try this already?

Comment: no.How to do that with CKEDITOR methods ?

Comment: Since you replied after 4 minutes how could you Google and try anything? Before asking it would be great if you took your own time to try anything, because the answer may be out there.

Comment: You're right ! I will try !